# Good touchpad for desktop computer

Tags: touchpad, odin, gesture

Touch gestures look so compelling in Odin that I would love to navigate elementary this way. But I installed it in regular PC and don't know what piece of hw will have the required support / drivers or features (i.e. 3 finger swypes)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't many great external touchpads that I've seen over the years, but the three options that have generally worked for colleagues using various versions of Linux include:

- Apple Magic Touchpad
- Logitech T650 Wireless Touchpad
- Miyoshi TTP-BT01 (I think this one might be Japan-only)

The Apple touchpad is the best supported of the three, but it's also the most expensive. If this is something that you'd like to try before you buy, then there are cheaper models on Amazon that go for under $50. Driver support will be hit-or-miss, though.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think something like the Logitech will work with the 3-finger gestures elementary provides?

Comment: The Logitech supports 4-finger gestures, so 3 should not be a problem 